# How to find Tensile Modulus of a layer of Plain Woven GFRP with GSM of Fabric given

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-analysis, applied-mechanics, solid-mechanics, composite

I need to Input "E" the tensile modulus for analysis of a composite layer made from Plain Woven E-Glass Epoxy composite material.
I know the GSM (g/m^2) of fabric is 106.
Using GSM =106, geometry of the laminate, can we determine tensile modulus of the resulting composite.

Thanks
RJ

Comment: Make and test. Will it be directionally affected.? Or get values for each and calculate likely results based on orientation.

Comment: We want to predict analytically prior to test. 
Its same in X and Y direction

Comment: So if you have two differents strings in parallel - how does the tensile strength combine? A bit of thought here…

Comment: Need Micro-mechanics model for woven similar to we have for Unidirectional layers. 
People working with Micromechanics of Composites can help

Comment: That’s the type of thing covered in mechanics of materials and simple mathe like trigonometry: sines of angles etc

Comment: @SolarMike Please share the link to appropriate forum if you know any

Comment: get the dumbest guy you can find to make a bunch of them. Then, if they are light weight things, screw them down to the parking lot in Walmart for a couple weeks.  If they are stouter, take them to the local quarry and let the dump trucks drive over them. Then test them. These are the numbers you want. Modeling them is going to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

For particle or short fibre unaligned reinforcement you use the volume fraction of resin, and for the fibres the Vf of that.

For woven fibres it is more complex and you need to account for curvature of the fibres. As such a method that examines a unit cell of the weave is needed, as discussed in any serious composite book, or DOI:10.1007/s42405-021-00365-z for example.